# Facebook graph photo thumbnail size

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, thumbnails

I have managed to pull out these images using PHP and JSON with Facebook's graph API. [This](http://graph.facebook.com/205120572858544/photos?limit=3&callback=?) is the URL I used. 
I only want 3 pictures from the album but I want all the pictures to be displayed in a standard size of 200x175px without distorting the pictures. How can I achieve this? (like displaying pictures in thumbnails in a Facebook album). [This](http://www.publicis-malaysia.com/fb_tab/garnier/json.php) is my testing page:

Comment: going for FUNNY CATS? :P

Answer (score 1):

What if you display the image inside a div with fixed height and width with overflow: hidden. The image won't be resized but at least all will be showed in the same size

Answer (score 0):

I am just thinking about this on the fly here, but try styling the "fbimg" class.

Like so:

```
.fbimg {

height: 200px;

}
```

If the images are going to be different (different heights and widths)...then I don't believe that you can keep them the same height and width without distortion. But if someone learns a trick how to do that...I want to learn it too. ;)

Comment: Hmm...well like I said...I really don't think it is possible to have a "set" height and width for the images without having distortion...because you have three different image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a:

```
style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px;"
```

to the "img" output of my parser. You can see all the thing in my github: https://github.com/kyuumeitai/Social-buzz/commit/0baf3c5a86e52e64e04796bdcf22a951eeaff291